# submitting contact form

Tags: php, email, sendmessage

I am facing problems in sending e-mail through my contact form
I can not determine where is the problem I think that I have done everything right but I am here to take the advice and I hope you will help me.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['subject'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['body'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $to = 'samir1986@gmail.com';
        $header = 'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>';
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($body)){
            mail($to, $subject, $message,$header);
            echo 'An e-mail have been sent successfully';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Please try sending e-mail again';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @user1716641...Did you check mail setting is enable on server?

Comment: Does not the header need to end in "\r\n"? Try changing $header to `'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Does SMTP server keep running on the server?

Comment: This wont work on a local machine..

Comment: If you are trying this on your localhost, you need to run an SMTP server/service

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've checked the value of each of your fields (for security reasons) then do :

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['body']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['body'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $to = 'samir1986@gmail.com';
        $header = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
        {
            echo 'An e-mail have been sent successfully';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Please try sending e-mail again';
        }
    }
?>
```